# How to create a c# desktop app to intercept web notifications?

Tags: c#, notifications, intercept

I would like to understand how to make a desktop application to interact with Chorme or firefox notifications.
in particular, I would like to know when a notification sends you to an address.

I followed this guide: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener#requesting-access-to-the-listener"

i can see "title" and "bodyText"
but i can't see the action related to the notification.
thank you